# Powershell fails on try to Add-Type from cs file that uses "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json"

Tags: c#, json, powershell

I have Powershell 3.0 with .Net framework 4.0 on Windows 7 x64. 
When I try to use a type from C# file that uses System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer I constanly get

> "Add-Type : t:\Powershell_Json_Test.cs(13) : The type or namespace
>   name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization' (a missing an assembly reference?)"

The error appears on line

```bsh
Add-Type -Path "$($MyPath)\Powershell_Json_Test.cs"
```

of Powershell_Json_Test.ps1. At the same time the $srs contains object System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer (as well as 400+ other objects). i.e. System.Runtime.Serialization.dll contains System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer and it should be available for usage.

Does anyone have idea why the error appears?

When I try to use Powershell_Json_Test.cs from c# code all works as expected.

Powershell_Json_Test.ps1

```bsh
$MyPath = $(Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
$srs = Add-Type -Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization -PassThru
Add-Type -Path "$($MyPath)\Powershell_Json_Test.cs"

$Hlpr = New-Object -TypeName "Test.Json.Helper"

$Obj = $Hlpr.GetInfo('{"Date":"2019-01-01","Result":2}')
```

Powershell_Json_Test.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Test.Json
{
    public class Info
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public int Result { get; set; }
    }

    public class Helper
    {
        public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
        {
            var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
            string retVal = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            return retVal;
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
        {
            T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
            var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
            obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
            ms.Close();
            return obj;
        }

        public Info GetInfo(string JSON) {
            return Deserialize<Info>(JSON);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just found how to avoid the error. I had to use

```bsh
Add-Type -Path "$($MyPath)\Powershell_Json_Test.cs" -ReferencedAssemblies System.Xml,System.Runtime.Serialization
```

instead of

```bsh
Add-Type -Path "$($MyPath)\Powershell_Json_Test.cs"
```

Comment: This was helpful getting some WCF svcutil generated code into PowerShell, thanks!